# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found - java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)

Tags: java

I am trying to perform a linear search, based on user input of the size of array, elements and the no, to be searched, however i am stuck with NoSuchElement issue due to Scanner issue, however i am not sure how to fix this, appreciate any help you guyz can extend.

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class LinearSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter no. of times you want to loop");
            int testCases = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
            for(int i=1;i<=testCases;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter size of array");
                int size=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                int[] arr = new int[size];
                
                arr = inputValues(arr);
                
                System.out.println("Enter no. to be searched");
                int find = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
                
                System.out.println("Calling search function");

                int arrayIndex = findIndex(arr, find);
                System.out.println(arrayIndex);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int findIndex(int[] arr, int find) {
        int arrayIndex =0;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            if(find == arr[i])
            {
                arrayIndex = i;
                return arrayIndex;
            }
            else
            {
                arrayIndex = -1;        
            }
            
        }
        return arrayIndex;
    }
    private static int[] inputValues(int[] arr) 
    {
        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            System.out.println("array length "+arr.length);
            for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());;
            }
            return arr;
        }
    }
}
```

`
Tried creating a different scanner object and closing it in inputValues function & tried creating a new scanner object for entering the number to find in the main function.

However both did not succeed.

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: Sample input used
Enter no. of times you want to loop
2
Enter size of array
3
array length 3
4
5
6
Enter no. to be searched
____ after this statement error was being thrown due to scanner object

Comment: if `Scanner` is closed, it also closes its input, in this case `System.in`, which will not be re-opened - Basic rule: never close a resource you did not open, unless documented differently

Comment: The common advice is to always close an `AutoCloseable` when finished with it, and that is correct advice, but there is at least one caveat to that rule: Do not close `System.in`. When you close your `Scanner` you are also closing `System.in`. In this case, remove the _try-with-resources_ statement around your `Scanner` (and ignore any relevant warnings given by your IDE).

Comment: No line found?  When you get the error for Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651) are you not getting a full stack trace?  The traceback should show where in LinearSearch.main the error occurred.  In any case, as people mentioned, you should start by getting rid of the try-block and just declare `final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);` followed by your "Enter no. of times..." println.